# How to add a checkbox form to a panel?

Tags: panels, forms

I have set up user comment email notification on my Drupal 7 site. When a comment is posted the author is notified by email. I did it using rules module as described [here](http://drupalize.me/videos/notify-author-comments#field_videola_cf_video:370000).

Now the user has the option to get notified or not. For this, I added a new boolean field checkbox on the user's account form page. So currently the user must go to his user account page to change this setting. I would like to make this setting available in a panel.

How can I add a checkbox to a panel in order to control that "notify me setting"? (The panel currently displays content type fields, comment forms etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define your own form and add it to a block in the panel.

After that, you save the value to the user account in the form submit handler.

**Background**:

[Form generation summary](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7)

**Relevant hooks:**

- [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) ( define form in a block )
- [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) ( return `$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('my_module_user_notify_form');` )

**and some custom functions you'll need.**

- my_module_user_notify_form ( return form array )
- my_module_user_notify_form_submit ( save to user )

If you use something like [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2), you could also just embed the relevant user profile form in the block. It would then handle the form build and processing for you.

Comment: How would I implement my_module_user_notify_form and my_module_user_notify_form_submit. Any tip, pointers? I am pretty clueless. Shall i use db_query?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to David's post, Panel now does let me choose my new block as content to add to the panel. I post the code below:

```
function mymodule_block_info() {
// This example comes from node.module.                                                                                                                                                 
$blocks['testblock'] = array(
                           'info' => t('Test'),
                           'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
                           );
return $blocks;
}

function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
// This example is adapted from node.module.                                                                                                                                            
$block = array();

switch ($delta) {
               case 'testblock':
                 //  case 'recent':                                                                                                                                                   
                 $block['subject'] = t('Test');
                 $block['content'] =  drupal_get_form('mymodule_example_form');
                 //krumo($block);
                 break;
              }

//return $block['content'];
  return $block;
}

function mymodule_example_form($form, &$form_state) {

 $form['notify_me'] = array(
                         '#type' => 'checkbox',
                         '#title' => t('Notify me by email when I receive a new message'),
                         '#description' => t("Check this option to be notified by email when you receive a new message"),
                         );

 $form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit'),
 );
 return $form;
}

function kl_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
// Validation logic.                                                                                                                                                                    
}

function kl_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// Submission logic.
```

}

Comment: So the error was that hook_block_view was returning $block['content'] instead of $block. I just did the edit in this post. Now the form displays!